# A couple questions about configuring xdebug for use in PhpStorm IDE

Tags: php, debugging, phpstorm, xdebug

So, I'm trying to configure PhpStorm to debug my application that's running on a Vagrant instance.  I have some gaps in my knowledge as far as how this should work:

Q1: The VM's php interpreter and php.ini are being used and PhpStorm lists a version of xdebug next to them as the debugger being used (example: "Debugger:xdebug.(insert version)").  If it didn't think that php was set up to use xdebug, it would have listed "Debugger:none".  phpinfo() also shows this same version of xdebug as the one being used.  How is this possible when the php.ini file I'm using has no mention of xdebug anywhere?  My understanding is that these two mechanisms (phpstorm debugger recognition and phpinfo()) use configuration to figure out what debugger I'm using.  Could the xdebug reference be in another .ini file?  I'm using php 7.

Q2: When I try and use PhpStorm's "Validate Debugger Configuration on Web Server" service it asks for a "Path to create validation script" and a "Url to validation script".  What do these two fields mean and what values should I give them if I want to validate the Vagrant box's Debugger config?

Thanks for any input.

Comment: 1) yes -- it's quite common on Linux. Just check `phpinfo()` output (top header) -- it lists all config files  that were processed.

Comment: Q1 : If they are not the default value, you can have a look in /etc/php5/conf.d/, you can have a file named for example 20-xdebug.ini. 
Q2 : Did you configure your PHPStorm to accept external connections for Xdebug ? (in Tools / Languages & Frameworks / PHP / Debug). If yes on which port ?

Comment: Hey all, thanks for your responses.  I've checked the secondary ini files used (conf.d was the directory checked for additional ini files) nothing called xdebug.  I do think that php storm is configured to accept extenal connections for xdebug, its using the default port which is port 9000.  Which port should I use?